# MS Access Case sensitive query giving incorrect result

Tags: ms-access

Why do these queries give different results? Reference is a single character column and I would expect to have a result giving counts for upper and lower case letter 'r'.

```
Select SUM(IIF(StrComp([REFERENCE],'R',0) = 0, 1, 0)) AS BIG_R,
       SUM(IIF(StrComp([REFERENCE],'r',0) = 0, 1, 0)) AS LITTLE_R
From [SYMREF]
Where [PROGRAM] = 'SOMEPROGRAM'
```

The result is that both BIG_R and LITTLE_R are the same and equal the count of BIG_R's

However,

```
Select SUM(IIF(StrComp([REFERENCE],'r',0) = 0, 1, 0)) AS LITTE_R,
       SUM(IIF(StrComp([REFERENCE],'R',0) = 0, 1, 0)) AS BIG_R
From [SYMREF]
Where [PROGRAM] = 'SOMEPROGRAM'
```

Again LITTLE_R and BIG_R are the same, but this time they equal the count of LITTLE_R's

This looks like a bug in the way MS Access processes this type of query, or have I missed something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access (or probably rather JetEngine) thinks that `StrComp` is called twice with the same argument and optimizes away one of the two calls.

A workaround is to compare the ASCII character values (`Asc("r") = 114`, `Asc("R") = 82`):

```sql
Select 
    SUM(IIF(Asc([REFERENCE]) = Asc('R'), 1, 0)) AS BIG_R,
    SUM(IIF(Asc([REFERENCE]) = Asc('r'), 1, 0)) AS LITTLE_R
From [SYMREF]
Where [PROGRAM] = 'SOMEPROGRAM'
```

Yet another workaround:

```sql
Select SUM(IIF(StrComp([REFERENCE],Chr$(82),0) = 0, 1, 0)) AS BIG_R,
       SUM(IIF(StrComp([REFERENCE],Chr$(114),0) = 0, 1, 0)) AS LITTLE_R
From [SYMREF]
Where [PROGRAM] = 'SOMEPROGRAM'
```

Here the two inputs to `StrComp` are clearly different. So, the second call not optimized away.

Comment: Thanks for you prompt answer... Looks like a case of over zealous qurey optimization in Access since StrComp by itself appears to be working as expected. Putting both together as I did causes the query to go off the rails.

Comment: Yeah, the optimizer unfortunately is overeager. My usual fix is appending a zero-length string to string fields, or incrementing numeric fields by zero. `Select SUM(IIF(StrComp([REFERENCE],'R',0) = 0, 1, 0)) AS BIG_R,
       SUM(IIF(StrComp([REFERENCE] & '','r',0) = 0, 1, 0)) AS LITTLE_R` should work. Note that constants are evaluated separately, so changing them won't work.